# Variable as array size in struct

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I implement a file's struct in my program but for some arrays in the struct I don't know the size. The size of the array is stored in another variable but it's unknown before the struct is filled in.

```
struct Vertex {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
struct myFile {
    ulong nVertices;
    Vertex vertices[nVertices];
};
```

That gives an error: "error C2065: 'nVertices' : undeclared identifier".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should store a pointer in your struct:

```
Vertex *vertices;
```

Then allocate the memory at runtime:

```
myFile f;
f.vertices = malloc(nVertices * sizeof(Vertex));
if (f.vertices == 0)
    handle_out_of_memory();

f.nVertices = nVertices;
```

Remember to free the memory when done:

```
free(f.vertices);
```

Comment: And remember to check that the allocation worked before using the pointer.

Answer (score 10):

C99 introduces 'flexible array members', which may be what you want to use.  Your code still ends up looking remarkably like the code suggested by [@frast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21683/frast), but is subtly different.

> #### §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
>   a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
>   of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
>   may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
>   recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
>   element of an array.
>
> [...]
>
> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. With two
>   exceptions, the flexible array member is ignored. First, the size of the structure shall be
>   equal to the offset of the last element of an otherwise identical structure that replaces the
>   flexible array member with an array of unspecified length.<sup>106)</sup> Second, when a . (or ->)
>   operator has a left operand that is (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member
>   and the right operand names that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced
>   with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure
>   larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the array shall remain that of the
>   flexible array member, even if this would differ from that of the replacement array. If this
>   array would have no elements, it behaves as if it had one element but the behavior is
>   undefined if any attempt is made to access that element or to generate a pointer one past
>   it.
>
> EXAMPLE Assuming that all array members are aligned the same, after the declarations:
>
> ```
> struct s { int n; double d[]; };
> struct ss { int n; double d[1]; };
> ```
>
> the three expressions:
>
> ```
> sizeof (struct s)
> offsetof(struct s, d)
> offsetof(struct ss, d)
> ```
>
> have the same value. The structure struct s has a flexible array member d.
>
> If sizeof (double) is 8, then after the following code is executed:
>
> ```
> struct s *s1;
> struct s *s2;
> s1 = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + 64);
> s2 = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + 46);
> ```
>
> and assuming that the calls to malloc succeed, the objects pointed to by s1 and s2 behave as if the
>   identifiers had been declared as:
>
> ```
> struct { int n; double d[8]; } *s1;
> struct { int n; double d[5]; } *s2;
> ```
>
> Following the further successful assignments:
>
> ```
> s1 = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + 10);
> s2 = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + 6);
> ```
>
> they then behave as if the declarations were:
>
> ```
> struct { int n; double d[1]; } *s1, *s2;
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> double *dp;
> dp = &(s1->d[0]); // valid
> *dp = 42; // valid
> dp = &(s2->d[0]); // valid
> *dp = 42; // undefined behavior
> ```
>
> The assignment:
>
> ```
> *s1 = *s2;
> ```
>
> only copies the member n and not any of the array elements. Similarly:
>
> ```
> struct s t1 = { 0 }; // valid
> struct s t2 = { 2 }; // valid
> struct ss tt = { 1, { 4.2 }}; // valid
> struct s t3 = { 1, { 4.2 }}; // invalid: there is nothing for the 4.2 to initialize
> t1.n = 4; // valid
> t1.d[0] = 4.2; // undefined behavior
> ```
>
> <sup>106)</sup> The length is unspecified to allow for the fact that implementations may give array members different
>   alignments according to their lengths.

The example is from the C99 standard.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error message looks like an MS Visual C error message, so C99 is out.  But, you can do a similar trick with earlier versions by declaring the last member with a size of 1.

Comment: @JeremyP: true - I keep forgetting that particular piece of ... well, is 'idiocy' too strong a term for it?  'Irksomeness' is a polite way of putting it.  The 'struct hack' you mention works in practice, though it is not guaranteed the same way the the flexible array member is guaranteed.

Comment: You've stated that `t1.d[0] = 4.2; // undefined behavior` is undefined behavior. Is this only because the memory was not allocated?

Comment: The information is copied direct from the C standard, so the C standard says it is undefined.  It is invalid because when `t1` was created, no space was set aside for the FAM.  For most purposes, structures with a FAM have to be dynamically allocated.  When it is allocated as an automatic variable, there is no space for the FAM.